# Sniffing 802.3 eth packets with socket raw

Tags: linux, network-programming, sniffing

I'd need to sniff on an interface BPDU (bridge protocol data unit) packets which are encapsulated in eth frames of type 802.3 with LLC header. I tried to open a socket raw:

`skd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_802_3))`

but trying to sniff packets i can't catch them. Looking at include/linux/if_ether.h seems that ETH_P_802_3 was a dummy type...is there a solution or i should use `ETH_P_ALL` and analize the EtherType field of the ethernet header?

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you sniffing locally or a segment?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not sure if your question is regarding the `ETH_P_ALL` flag or if your sniffer simply doesn't work.

I would recommend using `ETH_P_ALL` and decoding the headers yourself.

If your sniffers not working, make sure that you have promiscuous mode on?  From the command line, you can use `ifconfig eth0 promisc`, assuming your ethernet device is `eth0`.  Or you can set the `IFF_PROMISC` flag on your device using `ioctl`.

All that said, unless you have a good reason not to, it's probably strongly worth your while to not reinvent the wheel and simply use [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/).

Comment: Thank you Edward for the reply...Yes, with ETH_P_ALL all works very well and i can see captured my BPDU packets but with ETH_P_802_3 no packets are captured maybe because there is no implementation for this.